# How do i make this script run faster

Tags: php, mysql, json, cron

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$con    = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*******", "******", '*****');
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mybb_streams");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' . strtolower($row['channel']) . '?client_id=' . $clientId), true);
    if ($json_array['stream'] != NULL) {
        // turn them into variables to prevent outside SQL injection
        $displayname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $json_array['stream']['channel']['display_name']);
        $title       = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $json_array['stream']['channel']['status']);
        $game        = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $json_array['stream']['channel']['game']);
        $viewers     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $json_array['stream']['viewers']);
        $preview     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $json_array['stream']['preview']['medium']);
        $followers   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $json_array['stream']['channel']['followers']);
        mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES utf8mb4");
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE mybb_streams SET `online` = '1', `title` = '$title', `viewers` = '$viewers', `game` = '$game', `preview` = '$preview', `followers` = '$followers' WHERE `channel` = '" . strtolower($row['channel']) . "'") or die("A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Your Query: UPDATE `streams` SET `online` = `1`, `title` = `$title`, `viewers` = `$viewers`, `game` = `$game`, `preview` = `$preview` WHERE channel = '" . strtolower($row['channel']) . "'<br /> Error: (" . mysqli_errno($con) . ") " . mysqli_error($con));
    } else {
        mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE mybb_streams SET `online` = '0', `viewers` = '0' WHERE `channel` = '" . strtolower($row['channel']) . "'") or die("A MySQL error has occurred.<br />Your Query: UPDATE streams SET `online` = '0', `viewers` = '0' WHERE `channel` = '" . strtolower($row['channel']) . "'<br /> Error: (" . mysqli_errno($con) . ") " . mysqli_error($con));
    }

}
?>
```

This is the code that I used to update my streams list on the database. Problem is, the database is getting bigger and bigger, and this code is starting to run slow + take up my bandwidth. This script automatically runs every 3 minutes, and sometimes it doesn't update. So any suggestions to this code? So it can run faster, and more efficiently?

Comment: Profile your code by getting `microtime()` a few times in different places and comparing the values. It's likely that everything runs really well except reading from the remote server. It's also likely that there's little you can do about it.

Comment: Why not set a expiry column for `mybb_streams`? You can then query that table for streams that have not been updated in a while -- and skip the ones that have been polled already.

Comment: Try parallelizing the loop. Currently, you're doing many network requests in series.

Comment: What do you mean by "parallelizing" the loop? Can you show me?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 Problems :

**1 database access**

I think you should use mysqli_multi_query instead of doing one query by loop.

**2 HTTP request -file_get_content-**

You can make only one call using this

```
https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' . strtolower($row['channel']) . '?client_ids=' . implode(',',$array_clientId)
```

Like that you can get all the datas for all the ids at once.

then you parse the array into the loop.

try this --> https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/?client_ids=2,3,4 Yes, it's working

```
$con    = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*******", "******", '*****');
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM mybb_streams");
$array_ids;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $array_ids[] = $row;
}
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' . strtolower($row['channel']) . '?client_ids=' . implode(',',$array_ids)), true);
foreach($json_array as $user){ /* do your stuff */}
```

Comment: Problem is, I get the info from the database by the users who submitted their stream in the database. So I get them by channel name, not ids.